# Allow only certain operations to be concurrent

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm wondering if it's possible to make operations within a `NSOperationQueue` only concurrent with certain others. For example:

- Operation A - non-concurrent with all
- Operation B - can be concurrent with C (but not itself)
- Operation C - can be concurrent with B (but not itself)

Which could form a queue as below:

```
    B           B
A - | - B - B - | - A
    C           C
```

Is such specific concurrency conditions possible with `NSOperationQueue`?

The `concurrent` property of `NSOperation` is misleading in that it rather specifies rather the operation executes its task asynchronously (and in fact is now ignored since 10.6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a good situation for the use of dependencies. With `maxConcurrentOperations = 2` the last operation in the queue can be checked before adding another.

If **A**, make new operation dependent on that if the new operation is either **A**, **B** or **C**.

If **B**, make new operation dependent on that if the new operation is either **B** or **A**.

If **C**, make new operation dependent on that if the new operation is either **C** or **A**.